# Bootstrap collapsable Navbar isn't displaying the menu i.e the dropdown menu for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried creating a collapsable navbar for mobile devices, Although I used Bootstrap 3.3.6 an older version, because I am working on something. The Button shows up, but when I click on it nothing happens, it doesn't display the drop-down menu. I even copy pasted some code from Bootstrap components of 3.3.6 version, in the bootstrap site it works, but when I try the same in my html code it simply doesn't work. not sure what is actually happening here
this is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>A Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Square+Peg&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
              </div>
          
              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Here's my codepen link: https://codepen.io/MrROBOT_10/pen/gOoyyLe

Here's the Bootstrap components link : https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code pen it says jquery not available in the code pen console. So i added

```
     <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

just before the final the body tag
to get it working

Comment: Also if you can see in my code above I included the the jquery-3.6.0.min.js, it is the latest version. Why didn't it work? Is it because the Bootstrap 3.3.6 supports only the older version?

Comment: I see that now you should generally put script tags before the closing body tag or in the head, but yes you need lower than jquery3 for your version of bootstrap.Glad its working

Comment: Actually I placed it at the opening body tag and still working. Anyways Thankyou very much, this was a lot of frustrating. I was trying this for a few days now, but it just wasn't working, so I just left it, and thought of posting here. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem and yes it will still work after the opening body tag but, the browser will have to load the entire jquery library before it displays your content that is the reason its usually placed just before the closing body your page will load faster.